# Convert data from SQL to string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function, google-maps

**Problem:**

I am using Google Map API using the link: http://www.phpinsider.com/php/code/GoogleMapAPI/ - and when I try to print out an address on the map manually it will show up but not when selected from a database.

**PHP code (this works):**

```
$map->addMarkerByAddress('114 53 Grevgatan 31','The Tudor Arms','<b>The Tudor Arms</b>');
```

**PHP code (this does NOT work):**

```
$location = $row['postalnumber'] . ' ' . $row['address'] . ' ' . $row['city'];
$map->addMarkerByAddress($location , $row['name'],'<b>'. $row['name'] .'</b>');
```

**Desired solution:**

To be able to extract data from a table in an SQL database and send it to the Google Map API function.

Additional remarks: When I echo the variables above the address and all information will print out but not when sent to the Google Map API function. Do I need to convert the data into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should say google the format like:

```
$location = $row['postalnumber'] . ' ' . $row['address'] . ' ' . $row['city'];
$map->addMarkerByAddress("'".$location."'", "'".$row['name']."'","'<b>". $row['name'] ."</b>'");
```

Comment: Much appreciated, in addition I had to use htmlentities() in PHP because there was a problem with the Swedish characters ÅÄÖ.